# $\sum_{cyc} \frac{x^2+x}{x^2 +yz} \ge 4$ Inequality on a unit sphere's first octant

Tags: inequality, spherical-coordinates, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Given the portion of the sphere which is in the first octant: $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ ; $ x,y,z>0$ , show the following cyclic inequality:

$$
\sum_{cyc} \frac{x^2+x}{x^2 +yz} = \frac{x^2+x}{x^2 +yz}+ \frac{y^2+y}{y^2 +xz} +\frac{z^2+z}{z^2 +xy} \ge 4
$$

Equality occurs in the limit  $(1,0,0)$ and permutations thereof.

I have used 3d-spherical coordinates and the resulting function of $\theta$ and $\phi$ exhibits the inequality graphically.

I have also tried the following, using Cauchy-Schwarz and the spherical condition, which does not work (to save pain...):

$$
\sum_{cyc} \frac{x^2}{x^2 +yz}
\ge   \frac{(\sum_{cyc} x)^2}{\sum_{cyc} (x^2 +yz) }
=  \frac{1 + 2 \sum_{cyc} yz}{1 + \sum_{cyc} yz } =  \frac{ \sum_{cyc} yz}{1 + \sum_{cyc} yz } + 1
$$
Being very brave, it would then be enough to prove
$$
\sum_{cyc} \frac{x}{x^2 +yz} \ge 3
$$
however numerics show that this does not hold. Being not so brave it would be enough to prove
$$
\sum_{cyc} \frac{x}{x^2 +yz} + \frac{ \sum_{cyc} yz}{1 + \sum_{cyc} yz } \ge 3
$$
and I have  no clue on that one.

Comment: It is symmetric. Perhaps pqr method works.